# How do I calculate the eigenvalues of the positive partial transpose of this two-qubit state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, partial-transpose, linear-algebra

How can I calculate the eigenvalues of $\rho^{T_{B}}$ (PPT) of the following state

$$
\rho =\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes|+\rangle\langle+|+\frac{1}{2}|+\rangle\langle+|\otimes|1\rangle\langle1|.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

$$
\begin{align}
\rho^{T_B} &= \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes(|+\rangle\langle+|)^T+\frac{1}{2}|+\rangle\langle+|\otimes(|1\rangle\langle1|)^T \\
&= \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes(|+\rangle\langle+|)^\dagger+\frac{1}{2}|+\rangle\langle+|\otimes(|1\rangle\langle1|)^\dagger \\
&= \frac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes|+\rangle\langle+|+\frac{1}{2}|+\rangle\langle+|\otimes|1\rangle\langle1| \\
&= \rho.
\end{align}
$$

Now, we can obtain the eigenvalues using a result described in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14878/how-are-the-eigenvalues-of-rho-frac12a-rangle-langle-a-b-rangle-lang/15894) which says that the eigenvalues of

$$
\frac{1}{2}(|a\rangle\langle a| + |b\rangle\langle b|)
$$

are

$$
\lambda_i =  \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{|\langle a|b \rangle|}{2}.
$$

In our case, $|a\rangle = |0\rangle|+\rangle$ and $|b\rangle = |+\rangle|1\rangle$, so

$$
\lambda_i = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{|\langle 0|+ \rangle\langle +|1\rangle|}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{4}.
$$

Thus, $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\lambda_2 = \frac{3}{4}$.